# Sending an email automatically

Tags: android

I got this Bug list activity to report bugs in my apps. There is EditText and the button. I want the button to send email to me with text from EditText. I used some tutorial and came up with this:

```
        private void sendEmail() {
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "myemail@gmail.com");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "CFM - zgłoszenie");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description.getText());
            BugList.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        }
```

However it just opens emmail app with blank addres and subject field. I want them to be filled as above.

Comment: change "text/plain" to "plain/text".I am not sure about it.But give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
and
String[]{"recipient@example.com"}

```
        private void sendEmail() {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, String[]{"recipient@example.com"} );
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "CFM - zgłoszenie");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description.getText());
        BugList.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
```

Comment: ok, subjest is filled now, but the most important, email adress is still blank. However I'm running MIUI and using google email app, dunno if it might something to do with this

Comment: I think iot might be this: new String[]{"recipient@example.com"} - trying now